# Is there a way to show the kernel panic error message on the screen?

Tags: linux, kernel, debugging, kernel-panic, endeavouros

I'm currently running EndeavourOS, and I was wondering if there was possibly a way in to, in an event of a kernel panic, show the kernel panic message on screen/in the gui, similarly to a BSOD or mac kernel panic?

Comment: At the point a BSOD is shown, there really isn't much of a UI left. It's just a prettified static display of information.